# Is a continuous function on a compact subset of $GL(\mathbb{R}^n)$ bounded?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $\chi$ is a continuous function on $GL(\mathbb{R}^n),$ for example $$\chi(\alpha):=\left(1+\max_{1\leq i,j\leq n}|\alpha_{ij}|\right)^\ell\left(1+\max_{1\leq i,j\leq n}|\alpha^{-1}_{ij}|\right)^m|\det\;\alpha|^{1/p},$$
where $\alpha\in GL(\mathbb{R}^n)$ with coefficients $\alpha=[\alpha_{ij}]_{i,j=1,\ldots,n}$ and the coefficients of the inverse of $\alpha$ denoted by $\left( \alpha^{-1}_{ij}\right)$ and $m,\ell$ is a positive integers and $1\leq p\leq \infty.$

$\textbf{Question}:$ If we know the that matrix $\alpha$ is an element of a $\textbf{compact}$ subset of $GL(\mathbb{R}^n),$ say $\alpha\in \mathcal{G}$ where
$$\mathcal{G}:=\left(b: |\det\;b|\geq\varepsilon>0,\;|b_{ij}|\leq\frac{1}{t_o}  \right), $$
then it is true that $\chi$ is bounded $\forall\alpha\in\mathcal{G}$?

Comment: $\chi$ is certainly bounded. What do you mean by *uniformly* bounded?

Comment: @JuliánAguirre That $\chi$ is bounded for any $\alpha\in \mathcal{G}$

Comment: What do you mean by $\alpha_{ij}^{-1}$? If it is $1/\alpha_{ij}$ then $\chi$ is undefined for all $\alpha$ with a null element.

Comment: No, the power (-1) it  is symbolic.

Comment: The continuous image of a compact space is compact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a continuous function $\chi : GL(n, \mathbb{R})\to \mathbb{R}$ is bounded on any compact set $\mathcal{G}\subset GL(n, \mathbb{R})$. Namely, as $\chi$ is continuous, $\chi(\mathcal{G})$ is compact in $\mathbb{R}$, and the Heine-Borel theorem implies that we can choose an $M > 0$ such that $\lvert \chi(\alpha)\rvert\leq M$ for all $\alpha\in GL(n, \mathbb{R})$.